# "Call to a member function move() on null"

Tags: laravel

When I detect using `dd($ request-> toArray)` there is a `file` but when moving files with the `move` function an error occurs because there is no input please give an explanation about that- 1  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsGia.png)

`public function index_tambah(Request $request){

```
   //dd($request->toArray());

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),
            [
                'namaMtr'       =>'required',
                'jenisMtr'      =>'required',
                'hargaMtr'      =>'required',
                'platMtr'       =>'required',
                'imgmtr'        => 'required',
                'keteranganMtr' => 'required',      

            ],
            [
                'namaMtr.required'      =>'Nama Harus Disikan',
                'jenisMtr.required'     =>'Jenis Harus Diisikan',
                'hargaMtr.required'     =>'Harga Harus diisikan',
                'platMtr.required'      =>'Plat Harus Diisikan',
                'imgmtr.required'       =>'Image Harus diisikan',
                'keteranganMtr.required'=>'Keterangan Harus diisikan',

            ]       
        );

            if($validator->fails()){
                return redirect()->back()
                    ->withErrors($validator)
                    ->withInput();
            }

                    $file = $request->file('imgmtr');

                    $nama_image = $file->getClientOriginalName();

                        dd($nama_image);

                    $tujuan_upload = 'upload';
                    $file->move($tujuan_upload,$file->getClientOriginalName());


            $new_tawaran = new Motor();
            $new_tawaran->namaMtr       =       $request->input('namaMtr');
            $new_tawaran->jenisMtr      =       $request->input('jenisMtr');
            $new_tawaran->platMtr      =        $request->input('platMtr');
            $new_tawaran->hargaMtr      =       $request->input('hargaMtr');
            $new_tawaran->keteranganMtr =       $request->input('hargaMtr');
            $new_tawaran->imgmtr        =       $file->getClientOriginalName();


            $new_tawaran->save();

        return redirect()->route('show_data');

}`
```

Comment: That means that `$file`, returned via `$request->file()` is `null`. Ensure your file is being uploaded correctly. Also, please don't post your code as an image. Code is text, so copy and paste it into the question.

Comment: First of all, please edit your question and paste your code there, don't post it as an image. We can't help you like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you're using `$file = $request->file('imgmtr');` and there could be two problems:

If you're using default Laravel Request class, check your namespace on top of your controller, it should be like this: `Illuminate\Http\Request`.

If not that, you probably forgot to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your form opening:

```
<form method="POST" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data"> ... </form>
```